# SSH script with for loop

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, ssh

I would like to run script like this:

```
ssh -l user host """

j=0
for i in `ls -t`; do if [ $j -gt 1 ]; then echo $i; fi; j=$((j+1)); done;
exit

"""
```

But I always get this error:

```
bash: -c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

But if I ssh to host and then run:

```
for i in `ls -t`; do if [ $j -gt 1 ]; then echo $i; fi; j=$((j+1)); done;
```

it works,...

Why doesn't my script work?

Comment: Put your command within single quote. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/remote-for-loop-over-ssh

Comment: Woow, jap that is what do the trick :D